# xStream read child tag and set to parent pojo field

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I have an POJO which does not match the XML structure. For example:

XML:

```
<parent>
    <pField>temp</pField>
    <child>
        <field1>test</field1>
    </child>
</parent>
```

POJO:

```
class Parent {
    String pField;
    String field1;
}
```

Is there any option in `XStream` to read the value of `parent.child.field1` from XML and set it to `field1` in POJO?